# Printing Fibonacci Series having 2 similar codes but different outputs. Why?

Tags: python, fibonacci

**Resolve CODE 2 to print output as CODE 1 and give the reason why both of the codes have different outputs.**

Fibonacci Series

CODE 1

```
x = 0
y = 1
while x < 10:
    print(x)
    x, y = y, x + y
```

output
0
1
1
2
3
5
8

CODE 2

```
x = 0
y = 1
while x < 10:
    print(x)
    x = y
    y = x + y
```

Output
0
1
2
4
8

Comment: seems like homework, and one that could be resolved simply by debugging the code

Comment: In Code 1, `y` gets the *old* value of `x` added to it.  In Code 2, `y` gets the *new* value of `x` added to it.

Comment: CODE 2 gives me a different output: 0 1 2 4 8

Comment: @jasonharper but as per rule loop executes from downwards to upwards so how y get the different value of x

Comment: In the statement `x, y = y, x + y` the right hand side is evaluated first, essentially creating a tuple `(y, x + y)`, **then** that is unpacked into `x, y` so `x` gets the original version of `y`, and `y` gets the original version of x + y. On the other hand, you do `x = y` now `x` has the value of `y`, so `y = x + y` is the same as `y = y + y`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Those are simply not identical.
In the first code block y becomes x+y and in the second code block y becomes 2*y.

Just a quick note the output of the second code block is 0 1 2 4 8 and not what you wrote (this was fixed).

Comment: yes that output was my fault . But how that y becomes 2*y in CODE 2.

Comment: @HrithikMishra After you set x = y, x + y is the same as y+y=2*y.

Comment: @BenGrossmann means x is upside or downside of y, x will execute 1st and then y executes. Am I right?

Comment: @HrithikMishra I don't understand your comment, so I have no idea if you're right